# R under Mac suddenly does not allow access to lib

Tags: r, macos, upgrade

Only today I realized that R under Mac (both app and console) does not allow anymore upgrading/installing packages. It barks:

> Warning in install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l,
>   contriburl = contriburl,  :   'lib =
>   "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/"' is not writable

Can anyone explain what is going on and how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Have never experienced this on a Mac. This suggests that your permissions need to be scrubbed. The Disk Utility.app function in the /Applications/Utility/ folder is the typical method to approach this. If you need further training on managing your computer maintenance then search SuperUser.com

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to make it work again as before taking following steps:

1. cd /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/
2. sudo chown -R :staff 3.2/
3. sudo chown -R :staff Current

[where Current is just a symbolic link to 3.2/]

However I still to not understand what on Earth have happened... :-)

Comment: i would have run fix permissions in Disk Utility vs doing this. If you've switched between homebrew and official R binary installs, that could have done this. it's really strange behavior tho.

Comment: That would work only if I do not use El Capitan which has that horrible new version of Disk Utility which get control over user... :-(

Comment: `sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /`